# Show/ hide Spotfire web player toolbar buttons

Tags: spotfire

In spotfire web player customization there is and option to show or hide the toolbar by setting the value of the "showToolbar" property as true or false.
I need to show only few buttons of the toolbar such as Filter, and Bookmarks and i haven't found a way to do that.
Is it even possible? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Many times you need to log out for the settings to take place.

Answer (score 1):

You can [parameterize your dashboard](http://www.tibco.com/blog/2014/10/16/parameterizing-your-dashboard/). This is perfect for embedding dashboards on iframes or mashing up (embed) visualizations on websites such as Sharepoints or blogs that allows them.